# Ubuntu install on new PC raises hub error message

Tags: system-installation

I've built a new PC (AMD Ryzen 9 7000 series, AMD 7800XT GPU and an ASUS B650M-PLUS WIFI motherboard). I've updated my BIOS to the latest version and downloaded Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and flashed it on a bootable USB with rufus.

I get this error message when I try to install Ubuntu:

```
[    0.912218] hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
```

Sorry if this is a basic issue, this is my first time installing Ubuntu on to a desktop.